# Wallet recovery history

Tags: wallet-recovery

My Blockchain Wallet Has Been Hacked By Recovery Words.and my wallet id changed
How Can I Get Access To My Wallet Recovery History?

Comment: Blockchain.com wallet?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Most if not all wallet software don't keep logs as to who accesses recovery seeds or mnemonic phrases. (as would be stupid if not impossible)

(I'm assuming you're talking about Electrum here?)

The most you can do is see where your funds went using a third-party tool such as [Walletexplorer](https://www.walletexplorer.com/)

If you're lucky and he sent them to a regulated exchange, (coinbase et al), you can file a police report and they'll probably someday hand over the KYC data + IP adresses.

Don't get your hopes up though, your funds are gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reffering to the non-custodial wallet blockchain.com, you could attempt to login with those same recovery words (since the user-id/wallet-id login was compromised), and potentially acess a log of IP addresses that have logged into the service, and which could offer a clue (although perhaps not meaningful if the hacker used a VPN or other IP masking).